# gulp how to sync folders using gulp while ignoring some patterns

Tags: gulp

I want to sync two folders using gulp. I have managed to achieve this with the a package called gulp-directory-sync (see included task below), but now I need to exclude some files from the sync based on if the file or directory name starts with "__" (two underscores). I have tried to find a sync plugin with an ignore or exclude feature, but without success, so I am now wondering if anyone might know a workaround for this.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var dirSync = require('gulp-directory-sync');

gulp.task('sync', function () {
  return gulp.src('')
    .pipe(dirSync('./one', './two'));
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd always be *very* suspicious of "plugins" who break the gulp-way in the very first line. If you don't need files in `gulp-src`, you probably don't need gulp for that task, or there's something else fishy about it.

Gulp is already pretty good in copying files to someplace else, including exceptions, so why not use this built-in functionality? With the `gulp-newer` plugin we can make sure that we just copy those files that have been updated:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var newer = require('gulp-newer');
var merge = require('merge2');

gulp.task('sync', function(done) {

    return merge(
        gulp.src(['./one/**/*', '!./one/**/__*'])
            .pipe(newer('./two'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./two')),
        gulp.src(['./two/**/*', '!./two/**/__*'])
            .pipe(newer('./one'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./one'))
    );
});
```

Here's the same code with some annotations:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var newer = require('gulp-newer');
var merge = require('merge2');

gulp.task('sync', function(done) {

    return merge(
        // Master directory one, we take all files except those
        // starting with two underscores
        gulp.src(['./one/**/*', '!./one/**/__*'])
        // check if those files are newer than the same named
        // files in the destination directory
            .pipe(newer('./two'))
        // and if so, copy them
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./two')),
        // Slave directory, same procedure here
        gulp.src(['./two/**/*', '!./two/**/__*'])
            .pipe(newer('./one'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./one'))
    );
});
```

That might also do the trick, no plugins required ;-)

**Update**

Assuming that you just want to copy from `one` to `two`, and that you might have a watcher running, you can use the "deleted" event from gulp to check which file has gone:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var newer = require('gulp-newer');
var path = require('path');
var del = require('del');

gulp.task('sync', function(done) {
    return gulp.src(['./one/**/*', '!./one/**/__*'])
        .pipe(newer('./two'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./two'));
});

gulp.task('default', function() {
    var watcher = gulp.watch('./one/**/*', ['sync']);
    watcher.on('change', function(ev) {
        if(ev.type === 'deleted') {
            // path.relative gives us a string where we can easily switch
            // directories
            del(path.relative('./', ev.path).replace('one','two'));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: makes a lot of sense! I should probably give up my shameful addiction to grabbing the best sounding npm package without thinking it through first :).  The only thing this doesn't do for me is remove any files that no longer exist in the source.

Comment: Do you need to keep both folders really synched, in terms of if something in `two` changes, change the file in `one` back? If you just need to keep `two` at the same base as `one`, there might be a way

Comment: No, I don't need true sync, I just need to keep two at the same base as one.

Comment: I updated my answer. Using path.relative and a gulp watcher, you are able to listen to delete events. Maybe you should initially clean the directory and copy everything, but for ongoing development this should work like a charme