# How to sync a local folder with gulp, with update for deleted files and folders?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I am working on a WordPress plugin and have all the files in my working directory and run gulp in that project folder. Now, I'd like to have a watch task that copies all the changes to my local WP installation for testing.

Therefore I am looking for a way to sync (only in one direction) the project folder with the plugin folder of WP.

I managed to get it to work with [gulp-directory-sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-directory-sync)

```js
...

var dirSync = require("gulp-directory-sync");

var localDir = "../newDir/";
var buildDir = "./buildDir/";

...

function copy_to_local_folder() {
    return pipeline(
        gulp.src(buildDir+'**/*'),
        dirSync( buildDir, localDir, { printSummary: true } )
    );
}

function watch_local() {
    gulp.watch(buildDir+'**/*', copy_to_local_folder);


exports.default = watch_local;
```

However, the plugin hasn't been updated in 4 years and according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29880631/1786528), it is not doing it the proper "gulp way" (e.g. not using gulp-src) and this task should be possible with other basic gulp functions.

Copying changed files is pretty easy, but also keeping track of deleted files is more complicated. I also would prefer to only update changed/deleted/new files and not clearing the folder every time before coping all files.

Starting with the updated code in the aforementioned answer, I tried to implement it and made changes to make it work.

```js
...
var newer = require("gulp-newer");
var pipeline = require("readable-stream").pipeline;
var del = require("del");

var localDir = "../newDir/";
var buildDir = "./buildDir/";

function copy_to_local_folder() {
    return pipeline(
        gulp.src([buildDir+'**/*']),
        newer(localDir),
        gulp.dest(localDir),
    );
}

function watch_local() {

    var watcher = gulp.watch(buildDir + '**/*', copy_to_local_folder );

    watcher.on('unlink', function(path) {
        console.log(path);
        var newPath = './'+path;
        newPath = newPath.replace(buildDir, localDir);
        console.log(newPath);

        (async () => {
            const deletedPaths = await del(newPath, {dryRun: true, force: true});

            console.log('Deleted files and directories:\n', deletedPaths.join('\n'));
        })();
    });
}


exports.default = watch_local;
```

With this code, the folder gets updated when I change or delete files, but it does not trigger when I delete an entire folder. Which is probably because I use `unlink` and not `unlinkDir`. But even if I use the version of the function below, it doesn't get triggered by deleting a folder (with containing files).

```js
watcher.on('unlinkDir', function(path) {
        console.log('folder deleted');
        console.log(path);
        var newPath = './'+path;
        newPath = newPath.replace(buildDir, localDir);
        console.log(newPath);
    });
```

What am I doing wrong?
Or is there in general a better way to achieve this?

PS: I'm using
node v11.15.0
gulp v4.0.2
on Linux
deleting files and folders in VS Code

**Update:**

When I run it with:

- `watcher.on('unlink', ...`  and delete a file:
  it works
  with the `console.log` output and the `( async () => ...`
  and *Starting* and *Finished* for `copy_to_local_folder`
- `watcher.on('unlinkDir', ...`  and delete a folder:
  it works **not**
  nothing happens in the console output
  (not even *Starting*)
- `watcher.on('unlinkDir', ...`  and delete a file:
  *Starting* and *Finished* for `copy_to_local_folder`
  but not the `console.log` and `( async () => ...`
- `watcher.on('add', ...` and `watcher.on('addDir', ...`
  work both

Seems to me that the `watcher.on('unlinkDir', ...` does never get triggered ... is `unlinkDir` not supported by [gulp-watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch)?

Comment: Look at the log, speculation is synchronous asynchronous problem. If has Starting... , but not have Finished. Try like this (gulp.watch(xxx).on('change', gulp.series(async () => { xxx }, 'taskName', browserSync.reload));) Try use async function .

Comment: When I run it with `watcher.on('unlink', ...` it works when I delete a file (with the console logs, the `( async () => ...` and *Starting* and *Finished* for `copy_to_local_folder`) But when I run it with the `watcher.on('unlinkDir', ...` version and delete a folder, nothing happens in the console output (not even *Starting*). When I then delete a file *Starting* and *Finished* for `copy_to_local_folder` is in the log. To me it seems the `watcher.on('unlinkDir', ...` just doesn't even get triggered

Comment: In the docs for [gulp-watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch), it says *possible events* are `add`, `change` and `unlink` ; but then at the very bottom it says *All events from chokidar*: `add`, `change`, `unlink`, `addDir`, **`unlinkDir`**, `error`, `ready`, `raw`. Is `unlinkDir` maybe not fully supported by gulp-watch even so it is by chokidar?